# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

WTF? - this is becoming a nightmare, just seem to get error after error.. Im willing to pay someone for their time just to help me achieve what seems to be the unachievable, please.. alls I want is a dropdown menu that selects data from a table according to its category and displays it.. HELP! :(

```
<form action="portfolio.php" method="post">
 <select onload="displayProject(this.value);" onchange="displayProject(this.value);">
  <option value='none'>All</option>
  <option value='1'>Fencing</option>
  <option value='2'>Driveway</option>
 </select>
</form>

<?php 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'wlarter_user', 'pw', 'wlarter_portfolio');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$option= $_POST['option'];

$queries = "SELECT * FROM image"; 
if ($option != 'none'){
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM image where category=".$option; 
}

$result=@mysqli_query($db,"$queries");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>


<?php
}                      
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: why you are using this line of code?
"$queries=$query;"

Comment: STOP writing big letters for HTML. It is html 3.0 standard I think. We are not using HTML 3.0 anymore!

Comment: Any errors you receive?

Comment: Im new to php, this is some code I have managed to scrape together, forgive me for any mistakes..

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: Yes the error in the title @Xatenev ..
-
Code updated

Comment: $queries=$query;
$result=@mysqli_query($db,"$query"); This actually won't work. $query is NOT Defined

Comment: Define $query and it will work.

Comment: Wrote an answer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply turn it around, is probably what you want:

```
$queries=$query;
```

into

```
$query = $queries;
```

FULL code:

```
<FORM action="portfolio.php" method="post">
    <SELECT onload="displayProject(this.value);" onchange="displayProject(this.value);">
        <OPTION VALUE='none'>All</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE='1'>Fencing</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE='2'>Driveway</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</FORM>

<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'wlarter_user', 'pw', 'wlarter_portfolio');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$option= $_POST['option'];

$queries = "SELECT * FROM image";
if ($option != 'none'){
    $queries = "SELECT * FROM image where category=".$option;
}

$query=$queries;
$result=mysqli_query($db,"$query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    ?>

    <div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>


<?php
}
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Remove the @ before the mysqli_query so you see errors.

Comment: var_dump($option) please!.

Comment: Not sure what that is? is there anyway we could talk via skype? Im willing to pay for your services

Comment: My name is Xatenev in Skype.

Comment: You just should've checked the error, mate, like i answered. :3

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this.......

```
$result=@mysqli_query($db,"$queries");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
$result=@mysqli_query($db,"$queries");
```

with this:

```
$result=@mysqli_query($db,$queries);
```

it may help..

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of a mysql query can be a resource or a boolean value (if it failed), you should check the result of your query like this after executing it:

```
if ($result !== false) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ?>
            <div class="box-portfolio"> <?php echo $row['Img']; ?> </div>
        <?php
    }
}
else {
    // do your error message stuff here
    echo mysqli_error($db);
}
```